# How to Pass Values from a Double Handle jQuery Slider to a Rails Form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using [Slider Pips](http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/)'s double handled slider in a rails form. How do I pass the values from both slider handle locations to my rails controller as :min_sat and :max_sat? [This](https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/blob/master/dist/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js) is the JS file from Slider Pips.

This is the js

```
$(".element")
.slider({
    max: 1600,
    range: true,
    values: [1, 1600]
   }
})

.slider("pips", {
    rest: "label"
})

.slider("float");
```

and the html for the slider

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

generally speaking you'd use the `jquery-ui-slider` method: `.slider("values")` (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-values) which will return you an array of values.

---

You can either do it on form-post:

```
$(".element").slider("values");
```

and then send that to a hidden form field, or send it via `JSON` to your controller.

---

or you could update a hidden form-field in real-time like:

```
$(".element").on("slide", function( ui ) {
    $("#formField").val( ui.values );
});
```

and then post that form normally, and your controller can take care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot!

Comment: If it's correct, you can +1 , and accept the answer, that will help other people find it easier! :)